# The Simple way for the Polymer Backend

Tags: polymer

It is not clear to me how to use Polymer for implementing the backend. What is the natural way to process the backend for Polymer?  Please show brief sample code to be clear.

Comment: [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) is only a front-end library. However, it does support integrations with Firebase via [polymerfire](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/polymerfire). You could also create your own backend.

Comment: @tony19, Would you recommend link about "Query and persist Firebase data" @ https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase-pwa/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#25 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, Polymer.js is a front end library, specially to provide access to Web Components APIs as they are called.

There is no particular way to make a web request, in fact, though there are elements (iron-ajax) that can help, really you are on your own.

Given that polymer is mostly here to provide early access to Web Component development (and use), personally I decided to use fetch, the coming (low level, at least) standard for AJAX in Javascript.

Here is a link to a polyfill for the fetch API.

https://github.com/github/fetch

IOW: you are on your own making an ajax request, use the Fetch API or some other library of your choosing.

Then you build a RESTful back end and it doesn't matter what sort, though it's common to use Node.js with Express.

Comment: Your comment on iron-ajax and the fetch API is interesting.